# Save layout state of nested recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I think the title says it all. I have a nested recyclerview inside a recyclerview. What would the proper way of both saving and restoring the layout state of the nested recyclerview?

Comment: What do you mean "layout state" ? can you please post some sample code here

Comment: I think you should use the [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter), see ViewStates.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ... I solved it by using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` of manager associated with the nested recycler views